# xcmpQueue.Fail - NoPermission when I try to execute an XCM extrinsic via proxy

Tags: xcm, xcmp, proxy

I'm interacting with a smart contract on Astar via XCM message from another chain and through a proxy account with proxy type = "Any".

The XCM message arrives at the smart contract chain but fails:

```
xcmpQueue.Fail
error: XcmV3TraitsError -> NoPermission
```

The extrinsic points to an own smart contract, and I wrapped it with `tx.proxy.proxy`.
I don't understand why the proxy account doesn't have permission to execute it.